# How to edit a php file in joomla?

Tags: joomla-3.x

I need to edit a php file of a component, that is not accessible from backend / admin due to some error. However it wont reload when edited through FTP.

How to proceed? Or is it possible to disable and enable through admin that reload edited files?

Comment: Use a plugin and extended it. Do not override files just by editing them!!

Comment: Ok could you please provide some more information? Is some kind of plugin that makes me edit existing components php files in real time?

Comment: Well which PHP files are you trying to override? What exactly do you want to change in it?

Comment: JController::getInstance() change to => JControllerLegacy::getInstance()

In order to try to make it work with 3.X

Comment: Is there no 3.x comparible version of this extension?

Comment: unfortunately not...

Comment: "However it wont reload when edited through FTP." --> You probably have System-> Global Configuration -> System -> Cache Setting : ON. Try to turn it off.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try jextplorer. Of course such an extension is guaranteed to get your site hacked if not kept up to date.

Answer (score 1):

"However it wont reload when edited through FTP."
In addition to turning the Joomla "Cache off" as suggested by @webchn.

Delete the Joomla Cache "System-Delete Cache" (v3.4+).  Also, delete your web-browser's cache.

Some 3rd party templates support CSS/JS compression / optimization and store the optimized files in a directory.  The contents of this directory too should be deleted.